# UITableView and Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to do a simple Navigation controller controlled by a UITableView. Whenever I select one of the rows it is supposed to go to the next slide and animate there. Whenever I implement this code, the animation only goes halfway, then freezes, and then disappears.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
          description* desc=[[description alloc] init];
          [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:desc animated:YES];    
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the `description` class a `UIViewController`? If so, there is nothing wrong with this code and your problem is somewhere else, so you'll need to post more code.

Comment: having a classname start with a lowercase letter looks really strange to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the same problem, but something similar happened to me. The problem was that the `backgroundColor` of the `UIView` of my pushed `UIViewController` was clear, which cause the animation to look weird because we can see the pushing UIViewController underneath.

Setting `backgroundColor` on the `UIView` of the pushed `UIViewController` (in my case, in white) solved the problem